# Create Hyperlink on Cells with Values for a Specific Column

Tags: excel, vba

Goal: Link all cells on a specific Range (say Range B7:B47) from a specific column via Hyperlink that sends it to a cell from another sheet.

Per Range/Cell the hyperlink address changes by 50 rows.

Request help on how to fix this - apologies for the poor coding:

```
Range("B7").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A3"
Range("B8").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A53"
Range("B9").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A103"
Range("B10").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A153"
Range("B11").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A203"
Range("B12").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A253"
Range("B13").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A303"
Range("B14").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A353"
Range("B15").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A403"
Range("B16").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A453"
Range("B17").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Screenshots1'!A503"
```

Comment: Please show us what the source is and what the end result looks like

Comment: The source is Sheet1 Range B7:B47 - all cells should be filled with values if not then i want to stop the macro.

So for example the code would check for values from B7 to B47. The result I expect is for Sheet 1 B7 to Hyperlink to a Sheet called "Screenshot1" to a particular Cel which is "A3". Then Sheet1 B8 would hyperlink to Screenshot1 A53 cell and it goes on an on

Answer (score 0):

Process:

1. Define the variables
2. Initialize them
3. Loop through the cells in range
4. Validate if cell is not empty
5. Add the hyperlinks accordingly

Read the comments and customize it to fit your needs.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddHyperlinks()

    Dim evalSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim evalRange As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range

    Dim targetStartRow As Long
    Dim targetRowInterval As Long
    Dim targetRow As Long

    ' Customize this part
    Set evalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Screenshots1")

    Set evalRange = evalSheet.Range("B7:B47")

    targetStartRow = 3
    targetRowInterval = 50

    ' Set initial row
    targetRow = targetStartRow

    ' Loop through each cell in evaluated range
    For Each evalCell In evalRange.Cells

        ' Execute only if cell is not empty
        If evalCell.Value <> vbNullString Then

            ' Add the hyperlink to the evaluated cell
            evalSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=evalCell, Address:="", SubAddress:=targetSheet.Name & "!A" & targetRow, TextToDisplay:="Link"

            ' Increment the hyperlink target row
            targetRow = targetRow + targetRowInterval

        End If

    Next evalCell

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works